# Errors in Mixed Effects Model Code: "(p <- ncol(X)) == ncol(Y) is not TRUE" and "variable lengths differ"

Tags: r, error-handling, lme4

I'm pretty new to R coding and am trying to run a mixed effects model for the first time. My model is aiming to investigate the effects of populations trends of one species on population trends of another species over time (year being included as a fixed effect) with state being a random effect (since the data is reported by state, but I'm only looking at continental effects).

Here's a snippet of the set-up of my data (table called IGP):

```
 species  state Count_yr    population_value
1       A    AL     1970             0.1615
2       B    AL     1970             0.1981
3       C    AL     1970             0.2162
4       A    KY     1971             0.2096
5       B    KY     1971             0.2118
6       C    KY     1971             0.2784
```

I subsetted the data to keep all three species separate (1 subset for A, 1 subset for B, 1 subset for C) as follows:

```
A <- subset(IGP, IGP$species=="A")
B <- subset(IGP, IGP$species=="B")
C <- subset(IGP, IGP$species=="C")
```

Everything worked fine for a linear model focused only on one species:

```
Alm <- lm(A$population_value ~ A$Count_yr+A$state)
```

But things get hairy when doing the mixed effects model with all 3 species
incorporated:

```
lmer<-lmer(A$population_value ~ B$Count_yr*B$population_value + 
           C$Count_yr*C$population_value + (1|state)
```

First, I was getting a "variable lengths differ" error, so I went in and manually added NAs in for years and/or states that did not have data values for one of the species. I checked to make sure all years had the same number of data points and all states had the same number of data points, so I don't think there was an issue there after that.
Once I added the NA's, however, I started getting the error "(p <- ncol(X)) == ncol(Y) is not TRUE", which seems to be due to having NA values in factor columns. Going off of recommendations on other posts, I used na.omit to fix the issue, but then I got the "variable lengths differ" error again (seems like an endless cycle that I don't know how to fix yet).
If anyone could guide me as to how I should proceed, I would be super grateful! I'm not very knowledgeable about statistics or coding, so please let me know if there's any other information I could add to the post to make things clearer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve with the full model.  Are you trying to predict the population of species `A` from the populations of species `B` and `C`?  In that case, my suggestion would be to reshape your data from "long format" to "wide format" (using e.g. `pivot_wider()` from the `tidyr` package).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I'm trying to see if population A is affected by increased abundance of species B or species C. We know the population abundance already for all 3 species, but we want to see if overall trends of species B or C is affecting species A. What would  the change in format do to the data? Just reorganize columns/rows, or is the pivot_wider function doing something more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should convert your data from long to wide format. `tidyr::pivot_wider()` is one way to do this (but there are others, e.g. `reshape` in base R or `plyr::melt()`/`cast()`).

Sample data in long form:

```r
dd <- expand.grid(species=c("A","B","C"),
                  state=c("AL","KY","TN"),
                  Count_yr=1970:1974)
set.seed(101)
dd$pop <- rnorm(nrow(dd))
```

Convert to wide:

```r
ddw <- tidyr::pivot_wider(dd, id_cols=c(state,Count_yr), 
              names_from=species, values_from=pop,
                          names_prefix="pop_")
names(ddw)
## [1] "state"    "Count_yr" "pop_A"     "pop_B"     "pop_C"
```

Fit model:

```r
library(lme4)
lmer(pop_A ~ scale(Count_yr)*(pop_B+pop_C) + (1|state), data=ddw)
```

Comment: You're the best!! Thank you so much for your help, the new format worked great!